# Zend Framework, How to remove db-table?

Tags: zend-framework, frameworks

I created db-table like this,

```
  #   ./zf.sh create db-table TestModel admin
```

and now I want to delete the TestModel .

How can I delete the db-table created.

and One more question,its also Zend Framework question,

I want to create model(db-table) under the admin module.

like /modules/admin/model/(here)

I tried like this

```
#./zf.sh create model TestModel admin
```

but it create model into applications/models

How should I do to create the model into my moduels?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first part: just delete the files you don't want there is currently no way to use Zend_Tool (zf.sh) to remove components.

For your second question try this:

```
#./zf.sh create model TestModel -m admin
```

the -m tells the tool you want it to go to a module(this will create e regular model)
for a DbTable Model use

```
#./zf.sh create dbtable TestModel test -m admin
```

Comment: The full command for `create db-table` is `zf create db-table name actual-table-name module force-overwrite`. There is no `-m` argument

Comment: @ Phil I always have to use -m to specify a module it doesn't work otherwise. but you're correct about the thable name. I'll correct the answer

Comment: Thank you for your answer! May I ask one more question? How different 'model' and 'dbTable' ?

Comment: A DbTable is specific type of model in ZF. It directly relates to a specific table in your Database and by extending Zend_Db_Table_Abstract provides an interface for handling CRUD functions and relationships with that table and parent and dependent tables.